# If statement condition output the same image over each value of the array

Tags: php, html, css

The mercury is outputted the same with each time of the array, I want it to output once when the condition is met.

for example the following code is outputting:

```
mercury
<img>
3.76 m/s

mercury
<img>
9.04 m/s

mercury
<img>
9.8 m/s

etc..
```

I want it to only output:

```
mercury 3.76 m/s
```

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {

    $planets['mercury'] = "<img src='https://astronomy.com/~/media/695FA0F9A01044BF9C50E86C8E53A4E0.jpg' alt='mercury' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['venus'] = "<img src='https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fstartswithabang%2Ffiles%2F2020%2F07%2FVenus_in_Real_Color_Mosaic.jpg' alt='venus' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['earth'] = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/97/The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg/1200px-The_Earth_seen_from_Apollo_17.jpg' alt='earth' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['mars'] = "<img src='https://mars.nasa.gov/system/content_pages/main_images/418_marsglobe.jpg' alt='mars' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['jupiter'] = "<img src='https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/iEv6pmS4gfbefs5JbwHWiJ.png' alt='jupiter' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['saturn'] = "<img src='https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/system/stellar_items/image_files/38_saturn_1600x900.jpg' alt='saturn' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['uranus'] = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Uranus2.jpg/1200px-Uranus2.jpg' alt='uranus' width='100' height='100'>";
    $planets['neptune'] = "<img src='https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/eNTJrysq4A6DqXncBtsRrB.jpg' alt='neptune' width='100' height='100'>";

    $acceleration = array("mercury"=>"3.76", "venus"=>"9.04", "earth"=>"9.8", "mars"=>"3.77", "jupiter"=>"23.6", "saturn"=>"10.06", "uranus"=>"8.87", "neptune"=>"11.23");
    $start = ($_POST['start']);
    $end = ($_POST['end']);

    if (!empty($_POST['start'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['end'])) {
            foreach ($acceleration as $planetname => $value) {

                if ($start <= 3.76 && $end <= 3.76 && $planetname = "mercury") {
                    echo "<p style='color:white;'><br>" . $planetname . "<br>" . $planets[$planetname] . "<br>" . $value . " m/s<p style='color:white;'></p>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: Typo: `$planetname = "mercury"` should have `==` instead of `=`.

Comment: Why do you have a loop if you only want to output mercury?

Comment: Agreed with @Barmar and convert first 2 `if` into one like this: `if (!empty($_POST['start']) && !empty($_POST['end'])) {`

Comment: I also recommend revising your data structures. Instead of separate arrays for images and acceleration, use a 2-dimensional array with all the information for each planet. `$planets['mercury'] = ['image' => '<img ...>', 'acceleration' => 3.76, ...];`